# Issues importing animated models from Maya to Blender and then to three.js?

Tags: animation, three.js, blender, maya, autodesk

I have a simply question and hopefully someone can answer this. I need to get an animated model into three.js from Maya. I know currently the only exporter/ converter to the three.js JSON format that supports animations is the blender plugin. Unfortunately, my company works with Maya and Blender doesn't take FBXs. I already figured out that in order to do what I need to do, I need to export out of maya a Collada, import the Collada into Blender, then export out to three.js using the plugin.

But here is my problem. When importing the dae file from maya, I get an error:

> Sax FWL Error: Could not resolve sid "****" referenced in skin controller.

for each bone in the rig and nothing is connected properly.
I also tried exporting the fbx from other Autodesk applications but each one gives me the same errors.

Anyone know either how to resolve this error or another way to get a Maya animated rig into blender without error.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm trying to get my animations, including the morph targets, from Maya to Three.js.

Answer (score 1):

It may not answer your question but this two animations from the three.js repository use collada .dae format instead of JSON format supported by the ColladaLoader.js:

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada_keyframe.html

Answer (score 0):

I have created an updated version that also supports exporting rigged and animated models. It doesn't require any intermediate steps: it just outputs straight to a .JS file. We have a pull request to integrate the updated exporter with the THREE trunk, but if you want to get the new and improved exporter immediately you can get it from this repository: https://github.com/BlackTowerEntertainment/three.js/tree/maya_animation_exporter. The exporter files are in utils/exporters/maya.